# trying to display errors using Vuelidate prevent the staged form to proceed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to implement staged form validation using Vuelidate and I'm having a problem.
When I'm trying to add a span to present the error the form stop working. what do I mean?

I have this button to proceed from stage 1 to stage 2(stage 2 - where validation starts):

```
<button @click="updateStage(1)">Traffic Details</button>
```

updateStage function:

```
updateStage(value){
  //Move forward
  if(value === 1){
    this.currentStage++;
  } else { //Move backward
    this.currentStage--;
  }
},
```

I have this span to present an error:

```
<span class="redStar" v-if="v$.traffic.affiliate.$errors[0]">{{ v$.traffic.affiliate.$errors[0].$message }}</span>
```

these validations:

```
validations() {
    return {
      one: { required },
      two: { required },
      affiliate: { required },
      country: { required },
      five: { required }
    }
  },
```

and this function to check if the validations are good:

```
validationCheck: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      this.v$.$touch();
      if (this.v$.$error){
        //alert("Not working");
        return
      } else {
        this.updateStage(1)
        this.appendFields()
      }
```

After I added the span, I can't proceed to anywhere but the first stage, if I'm removing the span for the code the form is working properly
**What should I do?**

Edit - traffic inside Data():

```
 traffic: {
      one: '',
      two: '',
      affiliate: '',
      country: '',
      five: ''
    },
```

Comment: A span shouldn't affect how it works, check for the errors. Why do you expect `traffic` property to exist?

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console, traffic is define inside "Data" I will add it to code

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can help me in chat, I'm really stuck